# Detaching entities from Object Context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

In my model I have two classes Categories and Products. There is a relation many- to many between them. I'm using code first approach with Entity Framework. 
I'm trying to make a function which edit mapping between categories and products but I get an error.

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

I found that entities are still tracking after closing connection in Entity Framework.
So I assume that I have to manually detached entities from ObjectContext but my solution dont work. This is my controller code

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        ViewData["categories"] = _categories.GetAllCategories();
        ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name", product.CompanyID);
        return View(product);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection collection, Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _product.UpdateProduct(product);
            _product.EditMappingProductCategories(collection, product.ProductID);
            return RedirectToAction("ProductsList");
        }
        ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name", product.CompanyID);
        ViewData["categories"] = _categories.GetAllCategories();
        return View(product);
    }
```

My functions from services layer. I get new categories from form collecton and according to result I edit product.

```
public void EditMappingProductCategories(FormCollection collection , int pro) 
    {
        using (EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext())
        {
            List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
            Product product = context.Products.Single(m => m.ProductID == pro);
            foreach (var item in collection.AllKeys)
            {
                if(collection[item].Contains("true"))
                    list.Add(context.Categories.Find(Convert.ToInt32(item)));
            }
            //Check if produkt contains marked category in formCollection
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (product.Categories.Contains(item))
                {
                    product.Categories.Add(item);
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            //Check if product contains categories which are not marked in formCollection
            foreach (var item in product.Categories)
            {
                if (list.Contains(item))
                    product.Categories.Remove(item);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            UpdateProduct(product);
        }
    }
    public void UpdateProduct(Product product) 
    {
        using (EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext())
        {
            context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know which entities are still tracking. Is there any case to check it ? In debug mode or sth else ?

---

Thank you very much for solution. I didn't know this function. I made this changes and error disappeared but I have other problem. I attached product to context in update function but my categories weren't updated.So I set states of all categories on modified manually and when I watched in the debugger before saveChanges() function I saw that all of these categories were marked as modified.
But mapping between categories and product weren't updated in my database. 
Code of update function

```
public void UpdateProduct(Product product) 
        {
            using (EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext())
            {
                context.Products.Attach(product);
                if (product.Categories != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in product.Categories)
                    {
                        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }
                context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can ask another question referencing this one if you're still having problems (outside of the scope of this question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because each time you have a `using (EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext)`, the entities are attached specifically to that context. If you read entities out of one context, then try to attach them to another for an update, you will get the error that EF cannot track an entity in multiple contexts.

Try this when you are reading entities out of the context:

```
context.Products.AsNoTracking().Single(m => m.ProductID == pro);
```

By calling `AsNoTracking()`, you will ensure that the entitiy returned is not attached to any context. You can then attach it to another context during the update / save operation.

Comment: Thanks for this: it is an easy implementation in EF 6.1.